# Program stops working when using delete-operator

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I am new to using delete operators and I am a little confused on why I my program keeps crashing when I try to delete an element from a pointer array. It crashes on both deletes, I commented out the other for loop to test this.

```
int main()
{
    char ** str_array = nullptr;
    char * str = nullptr;
    char delimiter = ' ';
    int arraySize = 0;

    str = new char [51];

    cout << "Enter a string" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore( cin.rdbuf() -> in_avail() );
    cin.getline(str, 50);
    cin.clear();

    arraySize = StrToArray(str_array, str, delimiter);

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        cout << str_array[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
    {
        delete [] str_array[i];
    }
    delete [] str_array;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the function that I use to initialize str_array.

```
int StrToArray(char **& str_array, char * str, char delimiter)
{
    int size = 0;
    int arraySize = 0;
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ') 
        {
            size++;
            if (str[i + 1] == '\0' || str[i + 1] == ' ')
            {
                size--;
            }
        }
    }

    str_array = new char * [size];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str) + 1; i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\0') && !(str[i + 1] == '\0' || str[i + 1] == ' '))
        {
            str_array[arraySize] = new char[i-start];
            arraySize++;
            for (int x = 0; x <= i - start; x++)
            {
                str_array[arraySize-1][x] = str[x + start];

                if (x == i-start)
                {
                    str_array[arraySize - 1][x] = '\0';
                }
            }

            i++;
            start = i;
        }

    }
    return (size + 1);
}
```

My `str_array` is initialized as an array of pointers and each pointer points to a cString. 
What I am trying to do is delete each element of the array then delete the array its self. However, every time I try to execute either of the delete-operators my code crashes.

Comment: I hope you've mistyped here: `str_array[arraySize] = new char[i];`, and you've really wanted to say that you run that allocation in the loop. Otherwise it's incorrect, it won't allocate all the strings in `str_array`, and it also corrupts memory by writing beyond the limits of `str_array` array.

Comment: This is not a program, this is a tiny piece of a program, and we have no idea why it might be wrong seeing it out of context. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Vlad `arraySize` gets incremented on the next line within a for loop

Comment: You have a bug in your code, but it's not in the code you have posted (not counting the `delete` vs `delete[]` mistake). When you get errors during a `delete` almost always the bug has already happened. So show us the rest of the code.

Comment: @WhozCraig my apologies i meant to say its in a nested for loop. The I is the second for loop.

Comment: Related, do you have any idea how much of this code goes away with `std:vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: God yes, `vector<string>` why do things the hard way?

Comment: @WhozCraig we haven't learned of that yet...

Comment: @warrior5230 Its not your fault, but it seems most C++ classes are being taught like its 1980. Really it's quite amazing.

Comment: @john [stop teaching c](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk) should be required material for all C++ teachers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors I can see, both 'off by one' errors

```
       str_array[arraySize] = new char[i-start];
```

should be

```
       str_array[arraySize] = new char[i-start+1];
```

You haven't left enough room for the nul terminator.

And

```
str_array = new char * [size];
```

should be

```
str_array = new char * [size+1];
```

because the number of spaces is one less than the number of words.

I tested with "hello world" and with both those changes your code ran for me.

Oh, and the correction made by alijandro is right as well, but for me that didn't cause any crash.

Comment: After adding the brackets suggested by Alijandro and your solution my code was correctly executed and I no longer have any memory leaks. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Both of your `str_array` and `str_array[i]` is array, you should use `delete[]` operator to release them. See an simple example below.

```
void f(size_t size)
{
    char** str_array = new char* [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        str_array[i] = new char[i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        delete[] str_array[j];
    }

    delete[] str_array;
}
```

Comment: Even after adding the second set of brackets my code still crashes on the line `delete[] str_array[i];`